# Asp.net identity keep user login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

I have to keep user login for 15 hours but its logout after about 20 minutes of inactivity.

My code in `startup.auth.cs` is

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(15),
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                SlidingExpiration = true,
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                     OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
    }
}
```

Why user is logged out after about 20 minutes of inactivity?

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you want to keep session active then put this following key in web.config.
maybe your application session get expired in 20 minutes(it is default value )

```
 <sessionState timeout="900" cookieless="AutoDetect">
```

Comment: I want user to logout after 15 hours not 20 minutes. I have tried `ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(900)` but it didn't worked

Comment: @IrfanYusanif I have updated my answer, Please try this, if don't work then please let me know.

Comment: I have already already tried that solution and it didn't worked